# UWP Template Binding appears to be "Mode=OneTime"

Tags: uwp, binding

I have a templated control.  When I try to bind to a custom property using *TemplateBinding*, it appears to bind the the initial value, then doesn't change when I update that value.

```
<local:AnimatedUpDownBrush IsUp="{TemplateBinding IsUp}">
```

However, when I explicitly try to set the binding to OneWay, it works:

```
<local:AnimatedUpDownBrush IsUp="{Binding Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IsUp}">
```

What little documentation I can find on the subject says that TemplateBinding is the equivalent of the second example here, but that's clearly not the case.  Is something broken with the documentation or the way I'm trying to template bind?  Do you have to do something special when registering the **DependencyProperty**?

Comment: Wouldn't be surprising if documentation is outdated. I'd try to use [x:Bind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/templatebinding-markup-extension#xbind-in-controltemplate) there; should be something like `{x:Bind IsUp}` as long as x:Bind's default mode is set to OneWay and TargetType is assigned, e.g. in `<ControlTemplate x:DefaultBindMode="OneWay" TargetType="{your type}">`

Comment: Funny you should mention that.  I just got through trying the **x:Bind**.  It appears to be even more useless on a control template that **TemplateBinding**.  It didn't bind to anything.  The only thing that works in the second example from above.

Comment: If you add a callback about the DependencyProperty changes, when you update the value of IsUp, will this event be triggered? In addition, can you provide a simple sample that can be reproduced for us to test?